# can i override struts validate method inside action class execute method?

Tags: validation, struts, execute

I am new to Struts framework, currently I am developing a web based application using struts framework.

As we know that, in Struts application we can override the `validate()` in our user-defined Formbean-class to validate the user input, similarly can I override it inside my Action class's execute()?

If I can, after adding the ActionError object to the ActionErrors object, what all I need to do? Just help me with explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't *override* it, because Action doesn't define any `validate()` method. But you can perform validation in an action, yes:

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,
                             ActionForm form,
                             HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response) {
    ...
    ActionMessages errors = doSomeValidation();
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        saveErrors(request, errors);
        return mapping.getInputForward();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank You JB Nizet for quick response to my query, i am sorry i forgot the basic that, the Action class doesnot define validate(),but your answer hit my bulb,that helped me to come out of from my issue.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet .i have done,its working fine. Thank you once again.